# Shell script that reverses the order of the lines in the file

Tags: bash, shell

My assignment:

> Write a shell script that reverses the order of the lines in the file whose name is given by the first parameter and copies the lines it contains in reverse order to the standard output.
>
> Using `cat -n` and `sort -nr` sorts in descending numerical order, and `sed` can be used to remove predictable text.
>
> For example, if the file contained this:
>
> ```
> First
> Second
> Third
> Fourth
> ```
>
> The output should be:
>
> ```
> Fourth
> Third
> Second
> First
> ```

I cannot use `tac`.

Comment: `tac() { for x; do awk '{a[NR] = $0 }
                        END {for(c=NR; c>0; c--) print a[c]}' "$x"; done; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of `tac`, you can use a Perl script like:

```
perl -le 'while (<>) {
    chomp;
    push @lines,$_;
}
END{ print for reverse @lines; }'
inputfile
```

If your absolute requirement is to use `cat`, `sort` and `sed`, you could do:

```
cat -n file|sort -rnk1,1|sed -e s/^[[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]*[[:blank:]]//
```

This removes leading blank characters; the digits from `cat -n` and the blanks before the original lines of text.

Comment: it should be only with "cat -n and sort -nr" commands and i can use "sed" commands to remove predictable text.

Comment: @MottiCohen So add the line number with cat, use sort to reverse them, then strip the line numbers with sed.

Comment: @JRFerguson this is the error massege i get: sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unterminated `s' command